# fscanf() to take input

Tags: c, scanf

Here's my code:

```
FILE* fp,*check;
fp=fopen("file.txt","r");
check=fp;
char polyStr[10];
while(fgetc(check)!='\n')
{
    fscanf(fp,"%s",polyStr);
    puts(polyStr);
    check=fp;
}
while(fgetc(check)!=EOF)
{
    fscanf(fp,"%s",polyStr);
    puts(polyStr);
    check=fp;
}
```

Now if my `file.txt` is:

```
3,3, 4,4, 5,5
4,1, 5,5, 12,2
```

Now output is:

```
,3,
4,4,
5,5,
,1,
5,5,
12,2,
```

Now why is the first character of both the lines not getting read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `fgetc` call is eating the character.

You should read entire lines with `fgets` and then parse them with the `strtol` family.  You should never use any of the `*scanf` functions.

Comment: how do i prevent that? that was the sole reason i used check instead of fp. If check is incremented, why does fp gets incremented too?

Comment: ok,,i can use fseek.. but why is fp getting changed when i am doing fgetc(check)??

Comment: `check` and `fp` are two different pointers to the *same* `FILE` object.  To get two independent `FILE` objects you would have to call `fopen` twice.  But don't do that, and don't use `fseek` either.  Read entire lines with `fgets`.

Comment: "Never" is a strong word, but in 99 cases out of 100 plain `scanf` or `fscanf` is the path of madness.

Comment: @Zack and how will fgets help me here. I wont know how big my line is going to be.. i wont be declaring that big an array, though i have to divide the two lines of the file in to two different lists as they represent the polynomials with the coeff and the exp resp.

Comment: If your lines can be arbitrarily long, you have to `fgets` into a resizable `malloc`ed buffer.

Comment: Or use one of the many functions that read a line of text into a buffer allocated by the function (which means the caller is responsible for `free()`ing it).

Comment: The `*scanf` functions have a serious problem with numeric input.  Their behavior on numeric overflow (e.g., `sscanf("999999999999999999999999", "%d", &n)`) is *undefined*.  Reference: C99 7.19.6.2p10.

Comment: @Keith: I had been under the impression all "functions that read a line of text into a buffer [they] allocate [for you]" were nonstandard, but the FreeBSD manpages say [`getline`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getline) and `getdelim` are in POSIX.1-2008! I might actually start using/suggesting them now.

Comment: @Chris, @Keith: I don't recommend using `*scanf` even when numeric input isn't involved, because they don't tell you the *character* position of a syntax error, which makes it very difficult to recover from errors in a sensible fashion. (If your file is line-oriented and "discard lines containing syntax errors" is a sensible recovery rule, then the `fgets`/`sscanf` pattern can work, but I personally prefer to hand-code parsers until they get complicated enough to be worth breaking out `lex` and `yacc`.)

Comment: @Zach - I almost always use `fgets` to read, and generally use `strto*` for numeric conversions, but sometimes (usually for quick things) I cave and just use `scanf`. (Also, when parsers get that complicated, I recommend `lemon`. It's much cleaner to use than `yacc`. Even though you have to roll your own tokenizer (and have that call the parser, or call them both separately from a third source), it's not honestly that hard to do, and the benefits are, in my opinion, worth it.)

Comment: Yeah, I agree about `lemon`, I should have said "...breaking out a parser generator."

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about the format of the input data first.  Your list would seem to be better formatted if you only had `<coef>,<exp>` without the trailing comma.  In this way, you would have a nice pattern with which to match.  So you could do something like:

```
fscanf(filep, "%d,%d", &coef, &exp)
```

to get the values.  You should check the return value from fscanf to be sure that you are reading 2 fields.  So if the format of a line was a set of the following '`<coef>,<exp><white-space>`' (where white-space is either one blank or one newline, then you would be able to do the following:

```
do {
    fscanf(filep, "%d,%d", &coef, &exp);
} while (fgetc(filep) != '\n');
```

This code allows you to get the pairs until you eat the end of line.  The while conditional will eat either the blank or the newline.  You can wrap this in another loop for processing several lines.

Note that I have NOT tested this code, but the gist of it should be clear.  Comment if you have any more questions.

Comment: howcome if my input is `3,2 ` and so on, then 
`fscanf(fp,"%d,%d",&cof,&exp)` make `cof=3` and `exp=2`. Why doesnt the comma separating the two gets stored in `exp`?